# Why is String a class?

Tags: java, string, syntax

If it can be initiated with just

```
String s = "Hello";
```

then why is it a class? Where's the parameters?

Comment: You question has enough good answers already, just a note that you could also do: Integer i = 5; Long l = 6L; etc., while Integer is definitely a class too. Syntactic sugar.

Comment: @AssenKolov they are completely different in how they are implemented

Comment: @AssenKolov So basically, JVM magic? Never knew that, thanks

Comment: @Steve: Sure. See the question: why is xxx a class, if it can be instantiated this way. The answer: syntactic suger holds true for String, Integer etc.

Comment: String interning is handled by the language and JVM (interning). `Integer i = 5` is simply autoboxing (language). In addition `Integer.valueOf` does some pollng, but this is handled by the `Integer` class. I guess the end result to the user is that it's syntactic sugar.

Comment: How could i create an own class like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that `String` is such a useful and frequently used class, it has a special syntax (via a string literal representation: the text inside `""`) for creating its instances, but semantically these two are equivalent:

```
String s = "Hello"; // just syntactic sugar
String s = new String("Hello");
```

Behind the hood both forms are *not* 100% equivalent, as the syntax using `""` tries to reuse strings from Java's string pool, whereas the explicit instantiation with `new String("")` will always create a new object.

But make no mistake, either syntax will produce a reference to an object instance, strings are not considered primitive types in Java and are instances of a class, like any other.

Answer (score 12):

```
String s = "Hello";
```

is just syntactical sugar.  It's actually implemented as a reference type.  (It's an immutable reference type, so you can't change it)

Answer (score 7):

From the [§4.3.3 of the Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3):

> String literals are references to instances of class `String`.

And from [§3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class `String`

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "Hello";
```

JVM treats it as:

`String s = new String("Hello");` and interns it to `String` pool as `String` literal.

Comment: That's technically incorrect since your example is creating two `String` objects.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: Not sure what you mean, could you be more specific, so that I can correct my answer.

Comment: "Hello" <-- `String` object is created |||
new String(...) <-- `String` object is created

Comment: that is what my answer says too. I just added second line to say what happens internally. My answer didn't say anything that "Hello" won't be created in OP syntax.

Comment: They are not the same. `new String` always creates a new string object. `s = ""` checks the interned pool and returns a possibly already created string.

Comment: @kuo: Oscar answer is exactly what i meant.

Comment: refer language spec, as tim said, String literal is instance of class String.

Answer (score 0):

The line you have in the example is creating a String object. There aren't any parameters in the traditional sense that you are thinking of.