# Find all primitive memberProperties Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I want to find `memberProperties` that are not other classes I declared.

For example

```
data class X(val other: String)
data class Y(val str: String, val y: X?)
```

I want to `filter()` my `Y::class.memberProperties` such that only `str` is included.

In other words, I want to only return built-in types, such as java.util.Date, String, Int, Long, BigDecimal, Decimal, Double...etc and their nullable counterparts.

What I tried (and that doesn't work):

`Y::class.memberProperties.filter { it.returnType.javaClass.isPrimitive }` (returned 0 properties)

**Update:**

I managed to work around my issue for now like so:

```
Y::class.memberProperties.filter { !it.returnType.javaType.typeName.startsWith("com.myapp") }
```

However, this is plenty fragile as if I use any third party libs I might end up with types also included.

To make it clearer and give a more practical example, I am looking to exclude ALL types which, when serialized to JSON, do NOT serialize with properties beginning with `{`.

Comment: You question is not clear. You want to get your defined datatype or you want to check the data type is primitive or not ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli as it clearly states in the question `I want to filter() my Y::class.memberProperties such that only str is included.`

I don't want to check the data type nor do i want to check my defined type.
I want to get memberProperties which are NOT my types, e.g. `Int?, Int, Long, Long?, java.util.Date, String, String?` etc

Answer (score -1):

First of, in Java, Strings are *not* a primitive type.
Secondly, it seems the way to check it is to do `it.returnType.jvmErasure.java.isPrimitive`

For example

```
fun main() {
    Y::class.memberProperties.forEach {
        println("${it.name} is primitive: ${it.returnType.jvmErasure.java.isPrimitive}")
    }
}

data class X(val other: String)
data class Y(val int: Int, val str: String, val y: X?)
```

this will print

```
int is primitive: true
str is primitive: false
y is primitive: false
```

Comment: Ok i want all properties that are not a class, how do I do that?

Comment: @zaitsman I don't think there is a clear definition of what you consider to be a class. Because `String` is in fact a class

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717451/why-is-string-a-class